# Rebuild/refresh specific widget in PageView different class

Tags: flutter, setstate

I have a main screen containing a pageview. The pageview has three children, each being a separate class:

```
children: <Widget>[
      FirstScreen(),
      SecondScreen(),
      ThirdScreen(),
```

These screens load data from a database and are StatefulWidgets. I add data to that database from a separate screen that I open on my main screen.

I want to trigger the `setState` method for these three screens after I add the data to the database.

How do I access these screens when they are in a different class?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is State management.

There are various possibilities to ensure communication between business logic / storages and widgets.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

I can recommend BLoC and BlocProvider for state management. In simple words it allows your widgets to react on particular events, state changes in your app and separates business logic from views.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately using something like BLoC would require me to rewrite big parts of my app & which isn't an option at the moment. Is there any way to just access one specific widget from another class without any 3rd party tools?

Comment: If these 3 widgets have the same parent widget you can control them by the parent, providing for example `VoidCallback`, `ValueChanged` or other defined function types to spread the information. You can always do it dirty way as well, by defining `GlobalKey` for each widget in top Widget and access their states by `<GlobalKey>.currentState.<doThings>()`. Alternatively, use apply listeners to the desired Class and track parameter changes. However, I would still recommend proceeding with state management options. Link: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 0):

I added this to show the example, modify this for your database !

**Main Screen**

```
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  List<Map> list = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    list.add({'name': 'Raj', 'phone': '1234567890'});
    list.add(
      {'name': 'Naveen', 'phone': '1122334455'},
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text('Main Screen', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.white),
                onPressed: () {
                  addNewItem();
                })
          ]),
      body: Container(
        padding:EdgeInsets.all(15),
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Center(
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
                  return ListTile(
                      title: Text(list[ind]['name'],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                      subtitle: Text(list[ind]['phone'],
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)));
                }),
          )),
    );
  }

  void addNewItem() async {
    Map newItem = await Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (cc) => NewScreen()));
    if (newItem != null) {
      setState(() {
        list.add(newItem);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[image: main pic]
**New Screen**

```
class NewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewScreenState createState() => _NewScreenState();
}

class _NewScreenState extends State<NewScreen> {
  //Declare your new item here....
  Map newItem;

  //I m using strigns, but use TextEditingControllers here...
  String name = '', phone = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //database initialisation...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: onBackPressed,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text('New Screen', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),),
        body: Container(
          padding:EdgeInsets.all(15),
          color:Colors.white,
            child: Center(
                child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Name',
                                           labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    name = v;
                  });
                },
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Phone',
                                           labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                onChanged: (v) {
                  setState(() {
                    phone = v;
                  });
                },
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Add'),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (name.isNotEmpty && phone.isNotEmpty) {
                    newItem = Map();
                    newItem['name'] = name;
                    newItem['phone'] = phone;
                    //You may close new screen if you want !
                    //But call sendNewItemBack();
                  }
                })
          ],
        ))),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> onBackPressed() async {
    sendNewItemBack();
  }

  sendNewItemBack() {
    //add new item to database
    Navigator.of(context).pop(newItem);
  }
}
```

**After Adding**

[image: after pic]